# Updating .NET 5 DNX to to 1.0.0-beta6, having issues with missing version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

My project has the following dependency:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuthBearer": "1.0.0-beta6-*"
```

When it tries to restore it fails with:

```
Unable to locate Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions >= 2.0.0-beta5-206290920
```

I can't find that version on Nuget or MyGet.  Is this something I can get around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the latest version of the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions` package on MyGet: `http://www.myget.org/F/azureadwebstacknightly/`

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded `Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuthBearer` to beta5, doesn't seem to be any issues.